# How to solve this integral depending on parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

$g(\alpha )=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{\left | x-\alpha  \right | } } dx$

Given that f(x) is bounded, the question asked me to prove g(α) is continuous on R. The question is, I don't even know if f(x) is continuous. So it seems that I can't treat it as a double integral. So what else can I do?